# C# Interactive Location

Tags: c#, .net, f#, fsi, csi

I use F# Interactive every day, so I like launching it from cmd, not just Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. To do that, I have an environment variable called `FSHARPINSTALLDIR` in my `PATH` that points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp`. This allows me to simply type `fsi` to launch F# interactive.

Where is C# Interactive installed so I can do the same thing?

Comment: Most use Linqpad for these types of tasks.

Comment: Scott Hanselman blogged about doing this with .NET Core. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/CAndNETCoreScriptingWithTheDotnetscriptGlobalTool.aspx

Comment: I suggest you to look in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csi.exe`

Comment: @PetSerAl please submit your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct, that is add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn` to `PATH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With current Visual Studio version (15.8) C# interactive console binary should be installed in `MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csi.exe` relative to Visual Studio installation path.

IIRC, previous versions of Visual Studio install it under `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild` directory.

You can use following CMD command to locate its actual location:

```
dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\csi.exe" /s /b
```

Comment: When I run that command, I get (**_1_**) _`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csi.exe`_ & (**_2_**) _`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64\csi.exe`_. Please, can anybody share what the advantages might be of choosing one over the other on my Windows 7 machine? **_EDIT_**: BTW, those are from an older VS installation (*VS 2010?*). I also have another more recent installation of  _`csi`_ for VS2017 on a different volume.

Comment: Ah! OK. [_This answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42601857/4465539) helped me to understand the need for VS _**2015's**_ 32 bit and 64 bit versions of  _`csi.exe`_.

Answer (score 1):

Open Startmenu/Visual Studio 2019/x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019

type: **`where csi.exe`**

On my specific installation, output is: `Q:\VS2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csi.exe`

The location specific to your Visual Studio installation makes it a bit difficult to use in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good solution

1. i just went here 
   `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2019\Visual Studio Tools"`
2. I took the target command from the properties window wich for me looked something like this 
   `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell ee278031}"`
3. and the i slapped it into a bat file like this (I've done a bit of cleanup too)

`powershell.exe -noe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell ee278031}; cd ~; clear; echo 'Welcome back Massaynus!'"`

4. I managed to make this into a profile in microsofts new terminal and it works like butter

[Here is the profile if you are interested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa5zs.png)